# Jquery input name concanate with auto increment variable

Tags: jquery, concatenation

I created a table containing a button that adds a row to the table every time I click on it. 
The row created has 4 input, one of these input has an auto-suggest / auto-complete that search an information in the database and returns this information to the other 3's input fields. As the picture below

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmaiN.jpg

Code:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 var cnt = 0;
 var quantidadedisponivel;     

 $("#adicionar_item").click(function(){

    $('#tabela_publicacoes tr').last().after('<tr><td>#'+cnt+'</td><td><input type="hidden" name="titulopublicacao'+cnt+'" id="titulopublicacao'+cnt+'" style="width: 600px;"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="cod_publicacao'+cnt+'" type="text" disabled="disabled"></td><td><input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" name="valorunitario'+cnt+'" type="text" value=""></td><td><input class="form-control" name="quantidadedisponivel'+cnt+'" id="quantidadedisponivel'+cnt+'" type="text" disabled="disabled" value=""></td></tr>');        

     $('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).select2({
        placeholder: "Digite o título da Publicacao",
        ajax: {         
            url: 'autosuggest_busca_publicacao.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                var results = [];                   
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    results.push({                          
                        text: item.titulopublicacao + " - Número: " + item.numero + " - Ano: " + item.ano,
                        id: item.cod_publicacao,
                        quantidadedisponivel: item.quantidadedisponivel                         
                    });                     
                });
                return {results: results};
            }
        },
    }); 

$('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).change(function() {  
        var selections = ( JSON.stringify($('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).select2('data')) );
        //console.log('Selected IDs: ' + ids);
        console.log('Selected options: ' + selections);
        //$('#selectedIDs').text(ids);          
       $("input[name='quantidadedisponivel"+cnt+"']").val(selections);
    });

cnt++;

$("#anc_rem").click(function(){
    if($('#tabela_publicacoes tr').size()>1){
        $('#tabela_publicacoes tr:last-child').remove();
    }else{
        alert('Erro, não foi possível remover');
    }
 });            
});
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<table id="tabela_publicacoes" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
   <tr> 
         <th>Item</th>
         <th>Título</th>
         <th>Código</th>
         <th>Valor Unitário</th>
         <th>Quantidade Disponível</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="adicionar_item"><button class="btn btn-md btn-success btn-next">Adicionar Item</button></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anc_rem"><button class="btn btn-md btn-danger btn-next">Remover Item</button></a>
```

My problem is that I can not return the values ​​to input 3's. 
The statement `$("input[name='quantidadedisponivel" + cnt + "']") +cnt+`  with concatenated gives problem. Am I declaring the wrong way?

Comment: It seems you have it correct here, does it not work?

Comment: That should work. If it's not working, the problem is most likely with how you're setting `cnt`.

Comment: I'll bet the problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: start your loop count with a 1 instead of 0?

Comment: more informations added

Comment: You're not incrementing cnt, and there's a missing + operator in the concatenation

Comment: it already has +cnt+, it was a type error here in stack overflow

Comment: Is cnt referenced anywhere else? Your function will only be called once when the DOM is loaded (from what we can see) and only increments cnt once, and only after hooking up the event listeners. When said event listeners fire, its value will be 1, when I'd imagine it should be 0, do some work, then increment...

Comment: I have a table and i made a button that add a row every time i click in it, and the cnt is also incremented every time i click on this button.

Comment: Reformulated the question for better understanding